# Add subtype objects to list of supertype, then return list of subtypes from list of supertypes

Tags: c#

I have 3 interfaces.

```
public interface IItem
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IEquipable : IItem
{
    void Equip();
}

public interface IConsumable : IItem
{
    void Use();
}
```

`IEquipable` is implemented by the classes `Helmet` and `Bow`, and `IConsumable` is implemented by classes `Potion` and `Food`.

Then, I have a class with a property which contains a List of `IItem`, and proceed to add a few items of both `IEquipable` and `IConsumable` after instantiating it.

```
public class Character
{
    public List<IItem> Items { get; private set; }

    public Character()
    {
        this.Items = new List<IItem>();
    }

    public void AddItem(IItem item)
    {
        this.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
...
Character char = new Character();
char.AddItem(new Potion());
char.AddItem(new Food());
char.AddItem(new Helmet());
char.AddItem(new Bow());
...
```

Is there a way I can get a List of all `IEquipable` members from the List of `IItem`s, each AS `IEquipable`?

I want to do something like

```
    ...
    List<IEquipable> equipmentList = //do something to char.Items and get all items of type IEquipable.
    IEquipment equipment = equipmentList.First(...)
    equipment.Equip();
    ...
```

I've tried using `List<IEquipable> equipmentList = char.Items.OfType<IEquipable>().ToList()` but the resulting list ends up empty.

Comment: Real code would be useful. Your code doesn't compile. I fixed a simple typo, but you're also using `char` which is illegal as a variable name.

Comment: @Enigmativity congratulations on 100k, did you get a prize?

Comment: @TheGeneral - My wife hasn't divorced me, so I guess that's a bonus. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented (and fixed minor typos in) your code like this:

```
void Main()
{
    Character character = new Character();
    character.AddItem(new Potion());
    character.AddItem(new Food());
    character.AddItem(new Helmet());
    character.AddItem(new Bow());
    
    List<IEquipable> equipmentList = character.Items.OfType<IEquipable>().ToList();
}

public class Potion : IConsumable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void Use()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Food : IConsumable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void Use()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Helmet : IEquipable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void Equip()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Bow : IEquipable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void Equip()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface IItem
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IEquipable : IItem
{
    void Equip();
}

public interface IConsumable : IItem
{
    void Use();
}

public class Character
{
    public List<IItem> Items { get; private set; }

    public Character()
    {
        this.Items = new List<IItem>();
    }

    public void AddItem(IItem item)
    {
        this.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Your exact code (albeit `char` renamed to `character`) works perfectly fine. The `equipmentList` ends up with two elements. The issue you're seeing, i.e. "the resulting list ends up empty", is not reproducible with the code you've posted.

Comment: One of this days I'll learn to post actual code. I'm an idiot. I fixed it, so I'll edit and add actual code and reason why it didn't work in my case. For future reference.

Comment: @thexbuttonisntworking - Please post your fix as an answer to your question. Don't edit the question.

Comment: Roger, I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`OfType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-5.0) method

> Filters the elements of an `IEnumerable` based on a specified type.
>
> **Signature**
>
> ```
> public static IEnumerable<TResult> OfType<TResult> (this IEnumerable source)
> ```

**Usage**

```
var equipable = Character.Items.OfType<IEquipable>();
```

Or encapsulate it as a method in the instance or an extension method if you like

Answer (score 1):

So it does work like I wanted. My actual code just had another issue and I'm a dummy for not actually posting that. So here it is, for future reference.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using RolePlayGame.Library.Items.Backstage;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System;

namespace RolePlayGame.Library.Characters.Backstage
{
    public class Inventory
    {
        public List<IItem> StoredItems { get; private set; }
        public List<EquippedItem> Gear { get; private set; }

        public Inventory()
        {
            this.StoredItems = new List<IItem>();
            this.Gear = new List<EquippedItem>();
        }

        public bool HasItem(string name)
        {
            return this.StoredItems.Exists(item => item.Name == name);
        }

        public bool HasItem(IItem item)
        {
            return this.StoredItems.Contains(item);
        }

        public void RemoveItem(string name)
        {
            int firstIndex = this.StoredItems.FindIndex(item => item.Name == name);
            if (firstIndex != -1)
            {
                this.StoredItems.RemoveAt(firstIndex);
            }
        }

        public void RemoveItem(IItem item)
        {
            int firstIndex = this.StoredItems.IndexOf(item);
            if (firstIndex != -1)
            {
                this.StoredItems.RemoveAt(firstIndex);
            }
        }

        public void AddItem(IItem item, int quantity)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
            {
                this.StoredItems.Add(item);
            }
        }

        public void AddItem(IItem item)
        {
            this.StoredItems.Add(item);
        }

        public bool CheckEquipmentSlot(EquipmentSlot slot)
        {
            return this.Gear.Exists(item => item.UsedSlots.Contains(slot));
        }

        public bool HasEquipment(IEquipment equipment)
        {
            return this.Gear.Exists(item => item.Item == equipment);
        }

        public void AddEquipment(IEquipment equipment)
        {
            IEquipment alreadyEquipped;
            foreach (EquipmentSlot slot in equipment.SlotsUsed)
            {
                if (this.Gear.Exists(item => item.UsedSlots.Contains(slot)))
                {
                    alreadyEquipped = this.Gear.Find(item => item.UsedSlots.Contains(slot)).Item;
                    this.RemoveEquipment(slot);
                    this.StoredItems.Add(alreadyEquipped);
                }
            }
            EquippedItem newEquipment = new EquippedItem(equipment);
            this.Gear.Add(newEquipment);
        }

        public void RemoveEquipment(EquipmentSlot slot)
        {
            this.Gear.RemoveAll(equipment => equipment.UsedSlots.Contains(slot));
        }

        public int GetAttributeBonusTotal(AttributeType attribute)
        {
            int bonusTotal = 0;
            foreach (IEquipment item in this.StoredItems.OfType<IEquipment>().ToList())
            {
                bonusTotal += item.GetAttributeBonus(attribute);
            }
            return bonusTotal;
        }

        public int GetCarryWeight()
        {
            int totalWeight = 0;
            foreach (IItem item in StoredItems)
            {
                totalWeight += item.Weight;
            }
            return totalWeight;
        }

        public string GearToString()
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.Append("    Equipped Gear:");
            foreach (EquippedItem equipment in this.Gear)
            {
                builder.Append($"\n        {equipment.Item.Name}");
            }

            return builder.ToString();
        }

        public string ItemsToString()
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.Append("    Inventory:");
            foreach (IItem item in this.StoredItems.Distinct())
            {
                builder.Append($"\n        {item.Name} x {this.StoredItems.FindAll(value => value == item).Count()}");
            }

            return builder.ToString();
        }

        public int GetDefenseRateAgainstTypeTotal(DamageType againstType)
        {
            int rate = 0;
            List<IOutfit> outfits = this.Gear.Select(value => value.Item).OfType<IOutfit>().ToList();
            foreach (IOutfit item in outfits)
            {
                rate += item.GetDefenseRateAgainstType(againstType);
            }
            return rate;
        }
    }
}
```

One of the last lines has the problem (now fixed). `List<IOutfit> outfits = this.Gear.Select(value => value.Item).OfType<IOutfit>().ToList();` used to be `List<IOutfit> outfits = this.Gear.OfType<IOutfit>().ToList();`. But `Gear` is of type `List<EquippedItem>`, and `EquippedItem` is not an implementation of `IItem`.

Here is EquippedItem.cs

```
using RolePlayGame.Library.Items.Backstage;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace RolePlayGame.Library
{
    public class EquippedItem
    {
        public List<EquipmentSlot> UsedSlots { get; set; }
        public IEquipment Item { get; set; }

        public EquippedItem(IEquipment equipment)
        {
            this.Item = equipment;
            this.UsedSlots = equipment.SlotsUsed;
        }
    }
}
```

I needed to select the `Item` property from the items inside `Gear` as another list before doing the type filtering with `.OfType<IOutfit>()`. That's where `.Select(value => value.Item)` enters the stage.

So that's that. I'll learn to post actual code for future questions.